# Removing anchor tags from URL's

Tags: jquery, web

I came across an issue while using anchor tags during mobile (and desktop) browsing. When the link is clicked the anchor id is written to the url so www.mysite.com would become www.mysite.com/#anchor which causes an issue when the page is refreshed as it will the jump back to the anchor location rather than the page top (or the location the page was refreshed from). I posted a question about this and got a couple of responses that required multiple instances of the same code which seemed pretty inefficient. So after so fiddling I came up with this.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.js-anchor').click(function (evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            var anchor = $(this).text();

            $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $('#' + anchor).offset().top
            }, 1500);
        });
```

By making sure that the content of the link is the same as the id of the anchor, this will work perfectly. And you can have as many anchors as you want on the page as long as the class contains "js-anchor".

(html mock)

```
<a class="js-anchor">Top</a>

<span id="Top"></span>
```